# How to serialize a jira issue object in Python?

Tags: python, serialization, jira, pickle

I'm using the [jira Python library](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira) for fetching issues from a jira server. In order to reduce the server load and network traffic, I would like to store the search_issues() result locally in serialized form. If most issues would be available locally, I would need to query only these issues which were updated recently.

Unfortunately I ran into a problem, it seems a jira issue is not picklable. I always get the following error when calling dumps() for an issue:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'jira.resources.PropertyHolder'>: attribute lookup PropertyHolder on jira.resources failed
```

I also tried other Python serialization approaches (like marshal, dill, json), but the serialization fails for all of them (this is not too surprising because dill and json seem to rely on pickle).

Any idea how jira issues can be serialized in Python?

Comment: To my understanding, this is not that straightforward as one would think. Do you need all the information that the issue contains to be available locally?

Comment: I need quite alot of issue infos. I briefly counted the number of used attributes, at least two dozen issue fields are used. Sometimes I even need the changelog/history of an issue. I already thought about extracting all the relevant infos to a stripped-down issue object, but that's of course more effort than relying on standard Python mechanisms;-)

Comment: Well, the problem is that every `jira.resources.Resource` (comments, attachments, versions...) needs to be fetched separately from the server and converted to for example dictionary, and even more, resources might contain other `Resources` etc. I did something similar once but it took about 400 lines of code, and that was just for cloning tickets from one jira to another. Having the info locally available is even trickier.

Comment: And like you said, that is a lot of effort compared to something standard. I might be wrong, but to my understanding there is no "simple" way to solve this.

Comment: To do this I had to create local objects and copy the data into them, then pickle the local objects. Lots of work

Answer (score 3):

`jira-cache` package worked for me. It can cache an issue list and load it.

https://pypi.org/project/jira-cache/

Example:

```
def get_issues():
    jira = JIRA(auth)

    if not cache.exists():
        issues = jira.search_issues('project = BLAH')

        cached = CachedIssues(issues)
        cached.dump(open('issue_cache.json', 'w'))
    else:
        issues = CachedIssues.load(open('issue_cache.json'))

    return issues
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working.

```
    Changes needed to jira/resources.py

    Replace:
    top = type(str('PropertyHolder'), (object,), raw)
    with
    top = PropertyHolder(raw)

    and add at the end

    class PropertyHolder(object):

      def __init__(self, raw):
        __bases__ = raw
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```py
from jira.resources import Issue

# Saving an issue as json in some cache
issue = self.session.search_issues(some_query, maxResults=1)[0]
json = issue.raw
cache.set("my_key", json)

# Getting it from the cache and turning it back into an Issue object
json = cache.get("my_key")
issue = Issue(options=None, session=self.session, raw=json)
```