# How to store a dictionary of class objects

Tags: python, dictionary, object, storing-data

I am collecting a lot of jira tickets using the module here https://pypi.org/project/jira/

I basically have a series of queries that I run and I store the returned tickets as a list. Each list returned by each query gets its own key in a dictionary that holds everything. I'm then using Flask to display ticket information in a table that I make searchable using javascript.

I am having trouble storing the data for when the application has to restart. For example, `the Object of type Issue is not JSON serializable.` Similarly when attempting the pickle route, I get `Can't pickle <class 'jira.resources.PropertyHolder'>: attribute lookup PropertyHolder on jira.resources failed`

I have an sqlite database that I store user db.Models in with SQL Alchemy. Is there a way I might be able to utilize the db here? Any other methods for storing a dictionary of class objects?

Comment: I found my solution in another post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509348/how-to-serialize-a-jira-issue-object-in-python/54398996

Answer (score 0):

you can use do "`classObject.__dict__`" to get json

Comment: That will not return JSON and is not even guaranteed to return something JSON serializable.

Comment: @KlausD. I agree to your agree point. But may be in his case, Tune42 gets the required values.